# CSS Help- Contact form

Tags: css

I created my own contact form, however, now it moves on the page when I scroll by holding down control and moving my mouse.  What CSS do I use to keep it in place.  My website is straightforwardlaw.com my current CSS is:

```
#cntctfrm_contact_form {
background-color: #AAB6A2;
position: fixed;
color: #555555;

font-size: 11px;
height: 215px !important;
margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: -562px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 185px;
width: 400px !important;
position: static;
        overflow: hidden; 

  }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, try change position to fixed.

Comment: Unrelated, but I would suggest adding a [CAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) also.

Comment: add all your code with your question or chuck it into a jsFiddle. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position: static;` from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove static from position  it should be fine.